# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda(n)^s}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Does there exist $s>1$ such that the infinite sum:

$$\large \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda(n)^s}$$ converges?

$\lambda(n)$ denotes the Carmichael lambda function.

There exists a lower bound for the Carmichael lambda function.
$$ \large \frac{\ln(n)^{\ln\ln\ln(n)}}{\ln(2)} \ < \ \lambda(n) \ \le \ n-1 $$
Maybe there are better lower bounds, but if this inequality holds true for all $n$, then we have a valid lower bound.
This speaks for the existence of an $s$ such that the above infinite sum converges.

Unlike the Euler totient function the Carmichael lambda function has lots and lots of solutions.

For example $\lambda(n) = 12$ has 84 solutions.
$\lambda(n) = 36$ has 480 solutions.
Peter recently showed that
$\lambda(n) = 2 \ 570 \ 400$ has more than $4 \cdot 10^{32}$ solutions.

Which makes it difficult for determing $s$.

Or doesn't $s$ exist at all?

Comment: New result : $$\lambda(n)=4\ 108\ 104\ 000$$ has more than $10^{155}$ solutions, the largest being $$8.6780338174301768665703564826959954502 E2440$$ That indicates an enormous growth rate so that the existence of such an $s$ is in fact far from clear.

Comment: OP: the lower bound given doesn't quite imply that there exists an $s$ such that the series converges.

Comment: @Greg Martin I agree with you, and also pointed out that there may be better lower bounds. So this is an open topic.

Comment: You might want to clarify the sentence "This speaks for the existence of an $s$ such that the above infinite sum converges" then—to me that reads as the assertion that we agree is unproved.

Comment: Side note: $\lambda(n) \ge n^{1-\varepsilon}$ for almost all integers $n$, so this question (which I agree is interesting) is really about the frequency of small values of $\lambda(n)$.

Comment: @Greg Martin Again I agree. "This speaks for the existence ..." is meant by myself as a conjecture. So this is still an open topic.

Comment: Can we apply cauchy condensation test to the left hand side of the inquality to get that no such s exist?

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee You can show that no such $s$ exist _for_ the left hand side of the inequality, but that isn't enough to imply the result for $\lambda(n)$ itself. (Once again, similar to the comment above, the inversion makes the inequality go the wrong way; all we know is that $\frac1{\lambda(n)^s}$ is less than a function with a divergent sum.)

Comment: By a result of Florian Luca and Carl Pomerance: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/rangeoflambda13.pdf, we have the convergence when $s>1$.

Comment: It's not too hard to show this with the totient function instead by considering primorials and Mertens's third theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a proof here. I'm testing the convergence for various $s$ on my computer. It seems to state that:
$$ \large \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda(n)^{s}} \ = \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\phi(n)^{s-1}} \ = \ \prod_{p  \in \mathbb{P} } 1+ \frac{p^{s-1}}{(p-1)^{s-1} (p^{s-1}-1)} $$

with $\phi(n)$ denotes the Euler totient function.

This would imply a convergence for $s>2$.

**EDIT:**
Here is a table of my calculations on the finite series $$\large \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{\lambda(n)^s}$$
with $k=10^8+2$ and $s=3..10$ , compared with the value from $$\large \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\phi(n)^{s-1}}$$

```
        k=10^8+2
=======================================
s=3
3.1311004288577117696864213720672145564

eulerzeta(3-1)
3.3906420055725039161425956630026307937

delta
0.2595415767147921464561742909354162373
=======================================
s=4
2.4418898467785920718850990207528350883

eulerzeta(4-1)
2.4761947481650257943268554441251451600

delta
0.0343049013864337224417564233723100716
=======================================
s=5
2.2018982270301806556624353278588967010

eulerzeta(5-1)
2.2081507788908351865489237422333787799

delta
0.0062525518606545308864884143744820788
=======================================
s=6
2.0970782114226186216948296339931718612

eulerzeta(6-1)
2.0983791911959849323086032700100368562

delta
0.0013009797733663106137736360168649949
=======================================
s=7
2.0476698589254280847453302816006337832

eulerzeta(7-1)
2.0479610250731489197610146798912240357

delta
0.0002911661477208350156843982905902524
=======================================
s=8
2.0236306582504194280872581508156424955

eulerzeta(8-1)
2.0236987176793855141670768721518273505

delta
0.0000680594289660860798187213361848549
=======================================
s=9
2.0117661688685771820830540958591359923

eulerzeta(9-1)
2.0117825007331250530731924803744011605

delta
0.0000163318645478709901383845152651681
=======================================
s=10
2.0058710896288596447282831654385102224

eulerzeta(10-1)
2.0058750712442424355803812884050877697

delta
0.0000039816153827908520981229665775472
=======================================
```